# Multiple Keywords Banner Delivery in OpenX

Tags: openx

I have to show banners based on multiple keywords. I am using PAGE URL option containing multiple keywords separated by **+** sign.

Can you please tell how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can put delivery limitation for your banners so that you can put limitation for your banner delivery. Use variables in your url and can you variable delivery limitation.